# How do I style the default Formtastic labels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, styles, formtastic

I'm a new to Formtastic here.  How do I go about styling Formtastic elements? By default, the labels beside my form elements are colored white.  Is this normal or is it because I don't have a formtastic.css in my stylesheets folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out myself.

In my zsh shell in the directory for my Rails app,  I ran `rails generate formtastic:install`.

I also put in the requisite requires in my `application.css.scss` file:

```
     *= require formtastic
     *= require my_formtastic_changes
```

Following this, I just created a `my_formtastic_changes.css.scss` file in my stylesheets directory and implemented the following bit.

```
    <%= semantic_form_for @section do |f| %>
      <%= f.inputs do %>
       <div id="section-details">
         <%= f.input :name %>
         <%= f.input :category %>
         <%= f.input :description %>
         <%= f.input :filepath %>
         <%= f.input :site_section_id %>
       </div>
    <% end %>
```

I just then styled it in the `my_formtastic_changes.scss` with this:

```
    #section-details label {
        color: #000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is hardly anything special about styling `Formtastic` elements. You have to identify them in some `CSS` (or preferably `SCSS` nowadays) file and style it to your likings. Your favorite browsers `Element info` context menu will be very helpful in figuring out why an element is formatted the way it is.

If you desire a more specifc answer you should post the code of your `Formtastic` form together with the resulting `HTML` and a description of the label format you desire.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out myself though...and yeah I wasn't so specific with the question. My bad.